# Is there any way to convert LATEX characters into an after effects text?

Tags: equations, adobe, multimedia, video

Im doing a project in which I want to display mathematical expressions and equations in my video but after effects doesnt seem to have any tools that allow me to put latex into after effects.

For example:
$\int_1^2 \sin(x)\frac12$

Comment: No idea about the adobe software other than google suggests you can include png and other image formats so you could include a png of the  latex typeset text, it seems. But you may not consider that to be "text"

Comment: After effect supports [importing PDF/EPS files](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/kb/supported-file-formats.html#mainSupportedstillimagefileformats). Perhaps you can run latex to generate pdf, then import it in AE.